# Is there any way for `ls -d` when not passed any arguments to skip displaying `.`?

Tags: linux, find, ls, xargs

I have the results of a `find` command going through `xargs` to an `ls -d`. When no files match, I get:

`.`

as my sole output, because by default `ls -d` displays:

`.`

..., when no (filename) arguments are specified. Is there any way for `ls -d` to omit `.`, when passed no arguments and just display no output?

**Update**: You just cannot convince `ls -d` not to display `.`:

`.`

```
ls -d -A\                # Skip implied
   --hide=.\             # No, really, skip implied
   --ignore=.            # I mean it, damn it!
```

`.`

:)

Answer (score 2):

Using `xargs` together with `find` is sooo 1980s...

Call e.g.:

```
find . -type d -exec ls -d {} +
```

and the ls command will never be called without arguments.

The execplus feature has been added to `find` in 1989 by David Korn for SVr4.

Comment: Still, it would be nice to know how to get `ls -d` to not display anything (i.e., to skip the current working directory and or whatever directory is specified)

Comment: You may use e.g. `*` as the path argument to `find`. In this case the output would be empty in case that the working directory is empty. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

You tagged [linux](/questions/tagged/linux), so you probably run GNU xargs, which has this option:

```
-r, --no-run-if-empty
    If the standard input does not contain any nonblanks, do not run the command.
```

With `find ... | xargs -r ls -d`, `ls` won't be started at all if `find` doesn't match anything.

`find` might still match `.` explicitly. To avoid that, add `! -name .` to the find expression. Or use `-mindepth 1` (in GNU find) to prevent `find` from matching any of the paths given on the command line.

<sub>(As for how to have `ls` itself ignore `.`, I have no idea.)</sub>